# Como ocultar archivo en gitHub

Tags: php, github-pages

recien termine mi portfolio y contiene un formulario de contacto escrito con php (phpmailer) pero este contiene las credenciales del email desde donde envia el mail, mi consulta es: hay alguna forma de subir mi repositorio a github-pages sin que se vea ese archivo php y siga funcionando el formulario de contacto?

Comment: Si tu repositorio es público todo el mundo podrá ver esas credenciales. Si es privado no lo podrá ver todo el mundo, pero sí todos aquellos a los que concedas permisos para acceder a él. Generalmente aquellos archivos que tienen datos sensibles son ignorados con `.gitignore`  para que no sean subidos al respositorio. Si te interesa tener una copia de esos archivos es mejor guardarlas en tu propio servidor o equipo local en una carpeta oculta y protegida.

Comment: Entonces deberia conseguir otro host verdad?, porque en el caso que lo agregue a gitignore dejaria de funcionar mi formulario

Comment: No entiendo. Github no es un host para páginas web, es un sitio donde puedes alojar repositorios de código, pero no puedes usar ese código alojado en Github para hacer funcionar tu página web. Para que tu web funcione el código tiene que estar en ella y a la vez puedes tener una versión del mismo en Github.

Comment: con gihub-page podria subir mi pagina web, el problema es que quiero que no se vea el archivo php, pero que este para que siga funcionando el formulario

Comment: Te recomiendo que busques una solución que gire entorno a los [secretos de Gitbhub](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets). (Suena como un documental de Netflix sobre algo negativo de Github)

Comment: Yo no se como ocultar el archivo en donde están las credenciales de tu correo, pero una solución para tu problema seria activar la verificación en dos pasos para así evitar que alguien pueda iniciar sesión en el correo que has puesto.